# How to mix IPv4 and IPv6 in AWS WAF IP sets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, waf, amazon-waf

I'm trying to configure a rule in AWS WAF to block access to a particular URL except when the request originates from one of a set of trusted IPs. Naturally I'm trying to use IP sets for this.

My network connection appears to switch between a v4 IP and a v6 IP. Ideally I'd include both, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Even if I create an IP Set for IPv6, it won't allow me to express my v4 address as v6 (e.g. `0:0:0:0:0:ffff:183f:beef/128`)

The other approach I explored was adding two IP Sets as an "OR" condition. Unfortunately the rule builder (at least in visual mode) does not appear to support this.

I can't be the first to find myself in this position. What's the normal approach?

Comment: This site is unrecognisable. I've been here >10 years and have no idea why this is "off topic". No one bothered to leave an explanatory comment either.